# Reporting true game scores in Flash & PHP

Tags: php, flash, security, variables

HI, Im making a flash game and just wondering, how can I protect the ingame scores from being hacked ? For the moment im using a random number, which is set on the server and sent to the client, then using a hashing function which will hash 'score+randNumber' (a bit more complex, but the same idea), then i send the resulting score and the hash to the server (obviously logging attempted cheats). This so far works, but it is still easy to hack the score by decompiling the flash and finding out what the hashing formula is. Is there any other way that the scores can be transmitted to the server with little or no possibility of hacking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hash does not increase the security, but only the obscurity of your system, i.e. it makes it harder to enter fake scores in practice, but the theoretical hurdle stays the same. [Wikipedia has more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) on this class of "security". *Any* form of checksums and encryption will do nothing against an attacker who reverse-engineered your application's protocol - and that's hard, but not nearly has hard as it sounds.

The only hope you can have is to modify a significant portion of the game to a machine you control, i.e. your server. For example, a good idea might be for the client to send a "replay file" which contains all actions the user inputted, replay the game on the server, and then calculate the score on the server.

Comment: this is probably the only working solution, thanks. it wont work for my game, but it makes sense at least.

Comment: The problem remains the same: If someone would reverse engineer the way the "replay file" is built, they could fake one to do impossible things or whatever necessary to get higher scores.

Comment: true, it will also allow for replay attacks / etc, will need some reworking to store all previous games, add some analysis of who played what game.... but its not the kind of game im having, so im not even looking in the possibility of making it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move your business logic to the server side as that is harder to hack. Use flash just to print results not to store them. Do the hashing in the server not in the client, that way a  decompilation will not expose your logic.

Comment: im not sure how you can do that in flash, - essentially flash client is downloaded to the client's machine to be played, therefore it can be decompiled. it also means that if i dont protect it on the clients side, the scores can be changed..

Comment: before doing this you should understand what flash can do and web architecture especially server/client programming.

Comment: Well, im a security guy in the first place, so i think i know enough to say, that a flash is a client and that it HAS to be downloaded to the client's machine, therefore if the score is based on what client does in the game HE essentially controls, then its value should come from him. the only thing i can think off is making a polling system, which will make the client send his "current score" and if it changes a LOT, then the client is cheating. If you had something else in mind, please let me know. Programming is not an obsticle, problem is knowing what works and what doesnt.

Comment: Now I understand better what you want. You need a handshaking mechanism. Obfuscation and tough procedure to ban cheaters can also help.

Comment: Banning unfortunately is not an option. Its not a game where you will be able to achieve a lot, so user will be able to register again with different email address and spoil the score boards ;( Obfuscation is pretty much what im using now, but it wont work for long. So to summaries my options: its make protocol as obscure as possible & add a handshake & possibly add some low-cpu-bandwidth usage polling system.

Comment: a polling system that send the current score at second intervals in different points of the application to the server, combined with intermediary level updates and publishing the final score directly from server I think can be a good idea.  I dont know if you heard about this cheater detection using statistics, it seems to work pretty well. http://abcnews.go.com/Business/widespread-cheating-scandal-prompts-florida-professor-issues-ultimatum/story?id=11737137

Comment: yes, ive heard of it, but its too complicated and requires a lot of attention, while I would want to only do it once & update / change formulas every couple of month. The article is funny tho. cheating at the exam & getting caught - haha lolz. The way people should cheat is perform the same as if they have studied, BUT not study at all and party instead - everyone will be kept happy - lecturers, as they wouldnt see any 'cheaters' and students, because they would be partying LOlz

Answer (score 1):

Use AES encryption instead of hashing.

[as3crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) offers a good AES implementation, even though it requires some work on the PHP side.  [Here](http://www.zedia.net/2009/as3crypto-and-php-what-a-fun-ride/) is a working example you can use.

There is also a solution which uses JavaScript to encode on the client side.  You can download a complete package with PHP, JS, Flex and AIR code [here](http://code.google.com/p/as3-to-php-aes-dataservice/).

Comment: This is as bad as hashing :) - if decompiled / tampered with result, the cheating is once again posible.

Comment: Yes, theoretically it is possible to cheat, but because of the random padding, one would have to set up an application to mimic the game's behavior, instead of just calculating a hash.

Comment: oh, no you are mistaking - once decompiled (10 second job for me) you get to know EXACTLY how the protocol works (maybe a couple of hours to find out the formulas, but they are there never the less). so then you can mimic the protocol, instead of the game. easily done by everyone with spare time / little programming knowledge

Comment: I meant "the game's behavior" in terms of how and when to connect to the server, not the game engine.  True, a couple of hours might be enough to program it - still a lot better protection than a simple hash you can easily fake.  There is no absolute security, once you let clients connect to your server - someone with enough technical knowledge, time and determination will eventually find a hole.  You can raise the bar some, though - a couple of hours seem a lot when the goal is just to modify a high score list.

Comment: well, 'simple' sha1 is 256 bits.. AES is 128, DES is 56, and even MD5 would be good enough.. so hashing a padded value of the score seems to me as good as encrypting it with whatever the key it gets from the server.. its all the same really. hash functions are one way functions, so faking them would take quite a long time without knowing what was actually hashed, same as decrypting AES without a password. I can of course make it even more obscure by hashing a hash / etc :))